# Please help me understand why MySQL call is invalid

Tags: sql, mysql

Ultimately, my end goal is to provide a list of possible selections to a consumer based on his/her home state. I want this to be handled entirely through MySQL as we are trying as much as possible to create a truly dynamic site. If a member's state is not an issue, display all available actions. If a member lives in a 'issue' state, do not display that option.

I'll go ahead and start by listing example tables for my current issue:

### Table_A

```
ID  |     Name        |   value
-------------------------------
1   |       f         |   5.99
2   |       g         |   4.25
3   |       h         |   3.99
```

### Table_B

```
ID   |    state
---------------
2    |      NC
```

For a consumer coming from Arizona, his results would show:

```
1 - f - 5.99
2 - g - 4.25 
3 - h - 3.99
```

whereas from North Carolina (NC) it would be:

```
1 - f - 5.99 
3 - h - 3.99
```

because option 2 is not valid to him/her.

I believe the issue CAN be solved with a WHERE NOT EXIST but I would much prefer a join to accomplish the goal.

My initial query is:

```
SELECT a.name, a.value FROM Table_A a
JOIN Table_B b ON a.ID = b.ID WHERE
b.state != 'NC'
```

this does not work however

I THOUGHT I could also put the WHERE statement within the ON clause:

```
SELECT a.name, a.value FROM Table_A a
JOIN Table_B b ON (a.ID = b.ID AND b.state!='NC')
```

but this does not work either.

While I am happy reaching my goal, it is more important for me to understand why the JOIN I mention is not working.

Comment: What are you getting? You get all the values regardless? I don't see anything wrong with either of the statements and I would expect both of them to filter it correctly.

Comment: @cfreak - thank you for your help. I get no data returned whatsoever which is quite strange

Comment: I see. I didn't realize your "state" table had only the ones you want to exclude. @guido's answer is the correct one. JOIN only gives you rows that exist in both tables. LEFT JOIN gives you rows that exist even if the column you're joining on is null in the joined table. A better solution would be to populate your table with all the states because LEFT JOIN can cause performance issues if your tables are large

Comment: @cfreak - i Understand the difference in the left join versus inner but I'd like to better understand how the (is null OR...) statement affect the results. It was always my understanding in a left join that ALL results from the left table are shown regardless of match to the right tables

Comment: http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/  The link includes a link to the earlier article comparing when the columns are not nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bit cleaner:

```
SELECT 
  a.name, 
  a.value 
FROM Table_A a 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_B b ON a.ID = b.ID AND b.state = 'NC'
WHERE b.ID is null
```

Comment: your query also works but like Jeremy's above, I am hoping to find out 'why' mine wont work and the logic behind it

Comment: @JM4 - I'll try by breaking down your query: SELECT a.name, a.value FROM Table_A a
JOIN Table_B b ON (a.ID = b.ID AND b.state!='NC') Your query is only going to return rows for which there are matching rows in both table_a AND table_b, AND where that row in table_b is not 'NC'.  Since there aren't any rows in table_b that are both: not 'NC', AND matching in ID's, you aren't going to get any rows back.  Does that help?  :)

Comment: it does but even if i switched my initial query to a simple 'left join' the results returned are incorrect.

Comment: @JM4 - The difference between your query and mine is that mine matches on table_b with ID and state (note here: where state IS 'NC') and then in the where clause, limits the final result set to ONLY rows which have NO corresponding matching row in table_b (since all rows in table_b must have IDs).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table_B WHERE state = 'NC') b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.state IS NULL
```

I don't have access to my MySQL box at the moment so I can't test it, but I think it will work.  If not, I'll test it when I get home in about 30 minutes.

Comment: Jeremy - is there no other way to do it without a subquery being run? Your does work, but I actually want to understand why mine would not running a simple inner join. Of note, there will be 'several' other rules put into place here so just trying to minimize the amount of code and subqueries being run (for example, eventually a consumer will be filtered off their location, their age, their use of tobacco, etc and ideally return the result set of a single query).

Answer (score 1):

1- you should LEFT JOIN to get all result of table_a for which table_b.id = table_a.id OR table_b.id is null
2- in order to exclude "issue" state, only select from the join where state is not set, or set to a state different from the user's

So the query is:

```
SELECT a.name, a.value FROM Table_A a LEFT JOIN Table_B b ON a.ID = b.ID 
WHERE b.state is null OR b.state != '$user_state';
```

Comment: just saw your edit - it also works but like the two above, I want to understand more why mine would not.

Comment: @JM4 it's the type of <code>join</code> you are using in your query. Using plain <code>join</code> you get the rows in the cartesian product between table A and B for which A.ID=B.ID. With <code>left join</code> you get the rows above, *plus* the rows in A for which B.ID does not exists. Please not that Cyrena answer is better than mine. (mine does not work correctly if B.ID is not a primary key)

Comment: b.id is not a primary key and your answer does in fact work ;)

Comment: @JM4 not anymore if you *insert into Table_B values (2, 'FL');* BTW, adding those values demonstrating my query is wrong woulc actually *help* you understand better the difference between join, left join, and outer left join operations